# How to proceed when someone just states a requirement instead of asking a question

Tags: discussion, questions

How should I proceed when someone states a requirement instead of asking a question?

For example, how can I answer when:

1. The question is a requirement.
2. They have not shown they have tried anything themselves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may or may not apply to all sites but when someone simply states a requirement, instead of asking a question, my clarifying comment to them will often be along the lines of:

> For your question to attract a potential answer I recommend that you
> not only tell us what you want to do, but also precisely what you have tried
> to do and where you got stuck trying to do that.

I will often accompany such a comment with a vote to close as:

- needs details or clarity; or
- needs more focus

When I am writing my own questions I always include one question mark so that what I am asking is clear.